# Traefik Malformed Error using for ACME Lets Encypt Certificates & docker

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik, wildcard-subdomain

I'm unable to get my wildcard certs issued from `traefik`.  I use the `[docker]` configuration for all my backends.  On boot, I am seeing the following error for my various domains:

```
time="2018-05-16T05:41:39Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"<MY_DOMAIN_HERE>.com,www.<MY_DOMAIN_HERE>.com\" detected thanks to rule \"Host:<MY_DOMAIN_HERE>.com,www.<MY_DOMAIN_HERE>.com;ReplacePath: /best_path\" : cannot obtain certificates map[www.<MY_DOMAIN_HERE>.com:acme: Error 400 - urn:ietf:params:acme:error:malformed - Order's status (\"valid\") is not acceptable for finalization]"
```

You can see an abridged version of my traefik.toml here: https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/6e51b87ad176c95153b951b111c4b1cb

I'm not sure how to debug.  What information can I provide to yield a useful troubleshooting session?

Thanks!